# What is the meaning of "State-of-the-art closed-loop com gear"?

Tags: meaning

I`m just reading JET (by Russell Blake) and there I can read:
*Still watching the alley, she reached her throbbing hand down and quickly went through the fallen attacker’s pockets, noting the telltale smashed ear bud wedged under his head. **State-of-the-art closed-loop com gear** – as expected.*
What could be the meaning of **State-of-the-art closed-loop com gear**?
Could it be something like private communication channel with the highest technology level?
Thank you.

Comment: "State-of-the-art" means "newest".  "Closed-loop", in this context, means point-to-point, without going through WiFi or phone network or whatever.  (Can mean many other things in other contexts.).  "Com gear" is communications equipment.

Comment: @Hot You should make that an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"State-of-the-art" means "newest". "Closed-loop", in this context, means point-to-point, without going through WiFi or phone network or whatever. (Can mean many other things in other contexts.)  It also implies that the communications is two-way. "Com gear" is communications equipment.

Comment: In previous sentence, 'ear bud' is mentioned, which is the part of the radio communications gear.

Answer (score 0):

The communication might be point-to-point, dedicated, etc., as Hot Licks mentions.

However,  I take **closed-loop** **com** to have this established meaning:

> **Closed loop communication is a communication technique used to avoid
>   misunderstandings.** When the sender gives a message, the receiver
>   repeats this back. The sender then confirms the message; thereby
>   common is using the word “yes”. When the receiver incorrectly repeats
>   the message back, the sender will say “negative” (or something
>   similar) and then repeat the correct message. If the sender (person
>   giving the message) does not get a reply back, she must repeat it
>   until the receiver starts closing the loop. To get the attention of
>   the receiver, the sender can use the receiver’s name or functional
>   position, touch his or her shoulder, etc.
>
> [**Wikipedia**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_loop_communication)

which is also described in the following:

> [**Closed Loop Communications are Essential to Success**](http://growmap.com/closed-loop-communications/)
>
> ```
> Do NOT consider a message received until it is acknowledged!
> ```
>
> We need to use closed loop communications for every relationship and
>   especially important communications.

It might be difficult in the context of the book to make a decision on this.